# Prevent input in URL bar or disable URL bar in lock screen page

Tags: javascript, php

I have a lock screen page which requires password to unlock. I am not unsetting the `$_SESSION` variable here so I want something that will prevent user redirection. I was able to disable the clicking of previous button by using this code in the `head` of `lock_screen.html`:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    history.pushState(null, null, 'lock_screen.html');
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
    history.pushState(null, null, 'lock_screen.html');
    });
</script>
```

Now, I want to disable the URL bar or prevent the user to directly inputting addresses on the URL bar when they are in the `lock_screen.html`. How can I do this? Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Disable the URL bar? I would hate it if a website did that to me.  :o

Comment: As I have explained, this is a lock screen page, so I would like to prevent any user redirection.

Comment: Don't do this. You should avoid trying to override default browser behavior, especially when it comes to navigation. It makes for a poor user experience and is terrible for accessibility. Why do you care if the user tries to enter an address in the location bar?

Comment: The user might copy-paste the main page address directly on the URL bar instead of inputting the password on the lock screen page.

Comment: Then you should have a session variable that goes at the top of your main page that if not unset will keep redirecting the user to the lock screen until they do as directed